# How do I recognize if someone is suffering from hypothermia?

Tags: cold-weather, hypothermia

How can I recognize symptoms of hypothermia on myself and other people I camp with?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are the basic signs of Hypothermia

- Shivering. May start off mildly and go severe
- General apathy and sudden exhaustion
- Losing coordination (can't tie a knot, etc)
- Loss of concentration
- Sudden irrational behavior
- Unable to speak correctly (slurred speech, dropping words)

**Edit per comments**

- Final stages: Shivering can stop and subject can feel too warm and removing clothing

Comment: I've found that you can catch the apathy (usually they stop joining in on conversation), loss of co-ordination and concentration as pretty good indicators before shivering - make them eat something (a chocolate bar or something energy-packed) and, if possible, get another layer on them - keep an eye on them in case they progress further, but everyone I've done this with has bounced back enough to get them off the hill and into a warm hostel.

Comment: Summed up by saying to watch for the "-umbles": stumble, mumble, fumble.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that in the final stages the shivering can stop and the subject can feel too warm and start tearing off clothes - don't assume it's a good sign if shivering stops!

Comment: Precursors: Goosebumps, Blue lips/hands

Answer (score 1):

Please realize that there are various stages of hypothermia -- ranging from feeling very chilly all the way to death -- and the core body temperature is generally lower and lower at each stage. The following is from [northshorerescue.com/education/treating-hypothermia](https://www.northshorerescue.com/education/treating-hypothermia/).
The values are in Celsius. The article has a longer description of each stage.

> The international commission on alpine rescue classifies hypothermia into five stages based on core body temperature. Each stage can also be differentiated by clinical findings in the field when core temperature reading may not be available.

> **HT I**: Mild Hypothermia, 32-35 degrees
> Normal or near normal consciousness, shivering

> **HT II**: Moderate Hypothermia, 28-32 degrees
> Shivering stops, consciousness becomes impaired

> **HT III**: Severe Hypothermia, 24-28 degrees
> Unconscious, may be difficult to detect vital signs

> **HT IV**: Apparent Death, 15-24 degrees

> **HT V**: Death from irreversible hypothermia