# What is a Burrito wrap?

Tags: cold-weather, first-aid

I was going through one of the most amazing posts on The Great Outdoors which talks about [if sleeping naked in a sleeping bag keeps you warmer than with clothes](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/645/2303)

The is something said about Burrito wrap, and yes, I could simply google and find out what it is, but then there a reason why a forum such as The Great outdoors is preferred (by me, us).

What is a burrito wrap? When would I need it?

Comment: Burrito wrap is described here: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/1959/3362

Comment: Although a Burrito Wrap is referenced in a different question, this question specifically asks what a burrito wrap is. I don't believe this to be a valid use of the duplicate flag in this specific scenario.